# touchesMoved not functioning properly

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement an overriden touchesMoved func to enable SKSpriteNodes to be moved around by the user. However, I have to move the node very slowly for it to follow my touches when I drag. In addition, there are three SKSpriteNodes in the background (which you will see I explicitly set to .userInteractionEnabled = false) and these nodes will occasionally respond to the touches. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there are any other parts of the code you need.

```
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        var positionInScene = CGPoint(x: 375.0, y: 400.0) //sets a default position

        titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false
        drawingBoard.userInteractionEnabled = false
        sideBar.userInteractionEnabled = false

        for touch in touches {
            positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene) is SKSpriteNode {
                if (self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)).name == movableNodeName { //movableNodeName is the name assigned to all SKSpriteNodes that should be draggable
//I know this might be a strange way of doing it
                    (self.nodeAtPoint(touch.previousLocationInNode(self))).position = positionInScene
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix this issue by just setting the coordinates of the node that shouldn't move back to what they were originally whenever it is moved. This seems to work as I haven't been able to replicate the bug again in testing. If anyone could come up with a better solution though, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are using `touch.locationInNode(self)`, where `self` is your `SKSpriteNode`.  This means that your touch move code will only respond to what is going on inside of your `SKSpriteNode`.  What you need to do, is use either the parent of the sprite, or the scene, based on how you want to apply this logic.